# AvSession Fail with Bad_Access_Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcam

Im trying to save an AvAsset with multiple videos and merging them into a single video.
That part is taken care of though when the block completes it gives me an error.

My block:

```
-(void)exportDidFinish:(AVAssetExportSession*)session withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(BOOL success))completion {
self.exportSession = nil;

__block id weakSelf = self;
//delete stored pieces
[self.assets enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(AVAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSURL *fileURL = nil;
    if ([asset isKindOfClass:AVURLAsset.class])
    {
        AVURLAsset *urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
        fileURL = urlAsset.URL;
    }

    if (fileURL)
        [weakSelf removeFile:fileURL];
    NSLog(@"File Url: %@", fileURL);
}];

[self.assets removeAllObjects];
//[self.delegate removeProgress];

if (session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
    NSURL *outputURL = session.outputURL;
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            //delete file from documents after saving to camera roll
            [weakSelf removeFile:outputURL];

            if (error) {
                completion (NO);
            } else {
                completion (YES);
            }
        }];
    }
}
//Upload service
completion(YES);


[self.assets removeAllObjects];
}
```

This is the exact error I am receiving:
[image: Completion Block]

I would like to say I have a lot of experience with AVFoundation and the Assets though I do not and cant figure out why the completion block is failing.

What could be the issue and if you need anymore information let me know and i can update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had named my IBAction for the save button the name of the completionBlock so it was calling itself and failing.

Changed the name, and now it all works very good.